# Codeigniter and URL Rewrite on IIS 6

Tags: codeigniter, iis-6

I need to install Codeigniter on a shared host that runs IIS 6.0.
I know about the issues with URL rewrite. Also about Isapi Rewrite, but I cant install or set anything on this host. The starting page runs fine, but I cant access any other controller of the application, I always get a 404..
I tried to change the `$config['index_page']` and also `$config['uri_protocol']`, but nothing seems to work..
Is there some other way to get URL rewrite on IIS? Or maybe in PHP?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't install ISAPI Rewrite, look for

$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;

in application/config/config.php and set it to TRUE. This will disable the "SEO-friendly" URLs and use normal query strings.